# VBA scripts no longer work after SQL migration

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access

I recently migrated an Access database (that someone more knowledgeable than I designed) to MySQL, and linked the tables back into Access to use as a front end.  *Almost* everything looks great.  There is just one form and chunk of VBA code that doesn't seem to work.  There is a form that should show drop down menus and controls, but is blank in form view.  [The form in design view and form view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/242u2.jpg)  The VBA code that goes with the form is

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cmdPreviewPlate_Click()
'show user the new plate that is to be added to tblPCRsamples
On Error GoTo Err_cmdPreviewPlate_Click

'check whether boxes are blank
Dim bolBlank As Boolean
bolBlank = False

If IsNull(Me.Controls!cboChooseTemplatePlate) Then bolBlank = True
If IsNull(Me.Controls!cboChooseLocus) Then bolBlank = True
If IsNull(Me.Controls!txtEnterDate) Then bolBlank = True

If bolBlank = False Then
    'enable the Add button
    Me.Controls!cmdAddPlate.Enabled = True

    'generate the unique PCRplate from the template plate number and locus
    ' using the global variable GstrPCRPlateName so that the queries can add the plate name to both tables
    GstrPCRPlateName = Me.Controls!cboChooseTemplatePlate.Value & "_" & Me.Controls!cboChooseLocus

    'check: does this PCRplate already exist in tblPCRplates?
    Dim dbs As Database
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Dim bolDone As Boolean
    Dim bolNameExists As Boolean

    bolDone = False
    bolNameExists = False
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("tblPCRplates", dbOpenDynaset)

    rst.MoveFirst

    Do Until bolDone = True
        'does the new plate name automatically generated here = the value of PCRplate in the current record?
        If GstrPCRPlateName = rst![PCRPlate] Then
            bolNameExists = True
            bolDone = True
        End If

        rst.MoveNext

        If rst.EOF Then bolDone = True
    Loop

    'if the name already exists, make a new name by appending _ and the date
    If bolNameExists = True Then
        GstrPCRPlateName = GstrPCRPlateName & "_" & Me.Controls!txtEnterDate
    End If

    'set the value for the Locus
    GstrGetLocus = Me.Controls!cboChooseLocus

    'open the select query to show user what they're going to add to the PCR plates & samples tables
    Dim stDocName As String

    stDocName = "qryNewPCR_1SelectTemplatePlate"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName, acNormal, acReadOnly
Else
    'if user left fields blank (except page number, that can be blank), show an error message
    MsgBox "Choose/enter values for all the boxes"
End If

Exit_cmdPreviewPlate_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_cmdPreviewPlate_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_cmdPreviewPlate_Click

End Sub

Private Sub cmdAddPlate_Click()
'add this new plate to tblPCRplates and tblPCRsamples
On Error GoTo Err_cmdAddPlate_Click

'add the new plate to tblPCRplates
Dim stDocName As String
stDocName = "qryNewPCR_2AppendPlate"
DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName, acNormal, acEdit

'run the query to append the samples to tblPCRsamples
stDocName = "qryNewPCR_3AppendSamples"
DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName, acNormal, acEdit

'open frmPCRSamples to show the new plate has been added
stDocName = "frmPCRSamples"
DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, acFormDS

Exit_cmdAddPlate_Click:
Exit Sub

Err_cmdAddPlate_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_cmdAddPlate_Click

End Sub
```

So my question is, should the linked tables be causing errors?  Is there something I can amend to say that they are linked?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks for your help.  I know nothing of VBA (I mean, I can follow along) and have been tasked to destroy, I mean...admin...this database.  This is what happens when you give biologists computers ;-)  Even just some good resources would help a great deal.

Comment: When you first open the form, if it appears as in the Form View screenshot, that VBA code has nothing to do with the problem.  What is the form's Record Source?

Comment: Yes, I think they are two different problems.  But I'm hoping for one cause...

Comment: I'm going to try to run the select query in SQL and see what I get.  I'm not sure if it is related, but I used to be able to modify a record when I did a select query in Access but now that it is linked to MySQL, it won't allow me to (e.g.) enter a date for that one record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The happens when your `RecordSource` of the form returns zero records and the form or record source does not allow adding new records.

Check the record source (table, query, or SQL string) and run it manually to see if it returns records.

Comment: Ok, I ran the SQL query manually for the choose your plate and choose your locus controls.  There is no row source (RecordSource) for the others, because they are meant to be inputs (this worked before the migration, but is it wrong now?).

Comment: It seems to be the case.

Comment: Thanks.  Would you (or anyone) have any advice on how to set up a form where I choose a record from one table (Plate) and copy it with a modification (Plate_geneMod) to another table, while filling in some metadata (barcoded, date)?  Much appreciated.

Comment: Ok, the record source of the form was conflicting with some of the input controls.  I deleted the RecordSource query and it works now.  Thanks for your help!